# using a loop get unique values form a list then add another value

Tags: c#, generics, collections, loops, c#-4.0

Considering the following code is it possible to use a loop to add a common service to each unique machine.

```
internal static List<MyClass> Mc = new List<MyClass>();

public class MyClass : OtherClass
    {
        public string Machine { get; set; }
        public string Service { get; set; }

        public void AddProcessDetails()
        {
            Mc.Add(new MyClass { Machine = server1, Service = "notepad" });
            Mc.Add(new MyClass { Machine = server2, Service = "notepad" });
            Mc.Add(new MyClass { Machine = server2, Service = "foo" });
        }
```

So if there is a common service called “bar”, how can I loop thorough this list, get each unique machine name then add that machine name and service to the list?

Comment: You have a GetXX method that adds to a static list? Better fix up the typos (Mc/Md) and complete the example: What is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use some LINQ:

```
var query = Mc.Select(m => m.Machine).Distinct().ToArray();
foreach (string m in query)
    Mc.Add(new MyClass { Machine = m, Service = "bar" });
```

Alternately, you could add another `Select` to project with the new objects then add them via `List.AddRange`:

```
var query = Mc.Select(m => m.Machine)
              .Distinct()
              .Select(m => new MyClass { Machine = m, Service = "bar" })
              .ToArray();
Mc.AddRange(query);
```

Usually a query is against another source, but in this case since we are querying the same list you need to immediately execute the query by using `ToArray()` or `ToList()`, rather than LINQ's usual deferred (lazy) execution. Otherwise you will run into the `InvalidOperationException` since the collection is querying and the query source is also being modified.

Comment: I did have something very similar to this but Im getting an invalidOperationException was unhandled - Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: @Farstucker good catch. One way to fix this is to add `ToArray()` at the end of the query. The problem is the query is deferred and is being modified while we're adding to it. Will update.

Comment: That's because LINQ is lazy, when you enumerate query like this "Mc.Select(m => m.Machine).Distinct()" it will hold enumerator for Mc and would not release it until you finish with enumeration. So you should force query by converting it to array or list: Mc.Select(m => m.Machine).Distinct().ToArray().

Answer (score 3):

It may help..

```
var result = list.Select(x=>x.Service).Distinct(); 
forearch(MyClass cls in result)
{
     collection_of_myclass.add(cls);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net 2.0 then this will work for you... below is the sample code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
    Employee objEmp1 = new Employee("Rahul", "Software");
    Employee objEmp2 = new Employee("Rahul", "Software");
    Employee objEmp3 = new Employee("Rahul", "Back Office");
    Employee objEmp5 = new Employee("Rahul", "Back Office");
    Employee objEmp4 = new Employee("Rahul", "Engineer");
    Employee objEmp6 = new Employee("Rahul", "Engineer");
    Employee objEmp7 = new Employee("Rahul", "Test");

    List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();

    lstEmployee.Add(objEmp1);
    lstEmployee.Add(objEmp2);
    lstEmployee.Add(objEmp3);
    lstEmployee.Add(objEmp4);
    lstEmployee.Add(objEmp5);
    lstEmployee.Add(objEmp6);
    lstEmployee.Add(objEmp7);

    // TO GET THE GENERIC ITEMS
    List<Employee> lstDistinct = Distinct(lstEmployee);
}

public static List<Employee> Distinct(List<Employee> collection)
{
    List<Employee> distinctList = new List<Employee>();

    foreach (Employee value in collection)
    {
        if (!distinctList.Exists(delegate(Employee objEmp) { return objEmp.Designation == value.Designation; }))
        {
            distinctList.Add(value);
        }
    }

    return distinctList;
}
```